# What is the correct way to run a Flask application with Nginx and uWSGI in a reverse proxy case?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am a beginner and I am going to run my first Flask application. I have to deploy a Flask application with Nginx and uWSGI. The application is running on uWSGI but not in Nginx. I will reguest you to please see all the attempts I have mentioned below.The code is as follows:

## Attempt 1

api.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Thisisyoursecret"


# Create a simple endpoint /Hello with return message "Welcome to your flask application"


@app.route('/Hello')
def hello():
  res=make_response("Welcome to your flask application")
  return res


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

wsgi.py

```
from api import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

deploy.conf (I was instructed to put this in Virtual Host Config of nginx.conf)

```
 server {
        listen 8000;
    

location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;


}

location /Hello {
    alias /project/challenges/api.py;  (I doubt this)
}
```

}
uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
```

## The test code given in the question for testing my code is as follows: tests.py

```
import os

import pytest
import requests
from .api import app



class Test_API:

client = app.test_client()

def test_hello_from_app(self): 
    url = "/Hello"
    response = self.client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.data == b'Welcome to your flask application'
        
def test_hello_from_app_on_port(self):   
    url = "http://localhost:8081/Hello"
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text == 'Welcome to your flask application'

def test_hello_from_nginx_server(self): 
    url = "http://localhost:8000/Hello"
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text == 'Welcome to your flask application'    


def test_conf_file_contents(self):
    with open('deploy.conf', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        assert "location /Hello" in content
        assert "server localhost:8081" in content  
        assert "listen 8000" in content
```

the errors are: (404 status)

```
=================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 404 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost...
```

I am not allowed to edit the tests.py file. Its already written and read only.

I doubt the location /Hello{} block in deploy.conf.

The directory structure is:

```
projects
   |__challenge
        |_ __init__.py
        |__api.py
        |__deploy.conf
        |__wsgi.py
        |__uwsgi.ini
        |__ tests.py
```

## Attempt 2:

deploy.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
server_name localhost:8081;

location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;


}

location /Hello/ {
    alias /project/challenges/api.py;  
}
}
```

Kept rest same.

Got same errors

the errors are: (404 status)

```
=================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 404 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost...
```

## Attempt 3:

deploy.conf:

server {
listen 8000;

```
location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;


}

location /Hello/ {
    alias http://localhost:8000/Hello/;
}
}
```

Kept rest same.

the errors are: (502 status)

```
=================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 502 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost...
```

## Attempt 4:

deploy.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost:8081;


    location / {
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;


    }

    location /Hello/ {
        alias http://localhost:8000/Hello/;
    }
}
```

Kept rest same.

Got same error.

the errors are: (502 status)

```
=================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 502 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost...
In all the cases 1 error was common i.e Assertion error of "server localhost:8081".
```

I mentioned the test.py file which is actually testing my code, above. This file is already provided with question and I am not supposed to edit it.

Nginx server is starting fine. But I get those errors.

I suspect the location /Hello{} block.

Kindly suggest me what to do.

## Attempt 5

deploy.conf :

```
server {
        listen 8000;


location /Hello {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;


}
}
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8081
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
```

Error:

```
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 502 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost:8081'..
```

## Attempt 6

deploy.conf

```
server {
listen 8000;
location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;
}
location /Hello {
    alias http://localhost:8000;
}

}
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8081
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
```

Error:

```
====================================== short test summary info =======================================
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 404 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost:8081'..
```

Comment: You're getting closer. It's probably that `location /Hello/` in your nginx config that's throwing you off now. It might be easier to start with something small that works, and march forward. Try https://github.com/davewsmith/nginx-uwsgi-flask-starter

Comment: I have some questions - 1)What is unix:/tmp/uwsgi.socket indicating in starter.nginx? 2)How nginx will know in which port uWSGI is listening and where it has to pass the request? 3) starter.py is supposed to render index.html, but how nginx will make uWSGI understand that? Maybe these are dumb questions, but since I am a beginner, kindly clarify....

Comment: (1,2) This tells nginx to communicate with uwsgi over a unix socket (/tmp/uwsgi.socket). starter.ini tells uwsgi to use that same socket.

(3) in starter.ini, the `starter:app` tells uwsgi to looking in starter for a variable named app, which will hold an instance of an object that speaks the uwsgi protocol. Flask does that.

Comment: I added Attempt 5 and 6 in my post along with error. Request you to kindly look and give feedback.

Comment: That failing test is telling you, correctly, that "server localhost:8081" is no longer present in the deploy.conf.  Delete that test.

Comment: correction: delete that assert within the test

Comment: The test.py is provided with the question itself, in the platform where I have to do this exercise. Also, Its in read only mode. So I am unable to delete the assert "server localhost:8081" test.

Comment: What about the other error i.e FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 404 == 200 ?

Comment: Request you to kindly suggest how to deal with the error FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 404 == 200 ?

Comment: If you browse to http://localhost:8000/Hello and get a 404, that's what the test reflects. The first think to check is whether the flask development server ("flask run") also shows a 404 if you browse to http://localhost:5000/Hello

Comment: But also, you're mixing in checks that your server is running in to tests of your code. Consider splitting the tests that use the Flask test client out from tests that use requests and expect a live server. While developing, you want the former tests passing. When you deploy, you start caring about the latter.

Comment: I edited deploy.conf like this: server {
listen 8000; #server localhost:8081
location /Hello {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass http://localhost:8000/Hello;
}}. And now it worked. Thank you.

Comment: This started as a "too many problems" question, and turned into an extended debugging session in comments. No exactly what StackOverflow was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in another way.

Do the following changes in `deploy.conf` as below:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server localhost:8081
    
    
    location /Hello {
        alias /projects/challenge/api;
    }
}
```

Add the deploy.conf in nginx.conf.

Then click on Run. It will start the gunicorn server with this command:

```
export FLASK_APP=api; export FLASK_ENV=development;gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8081 wsgi:app
```

Now manually open another terminal and run the following command:

```
export FLASK_APP=api; export FLASK_ENV=development;gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app
```

Now your test cases might pass, I think. Try and let me know,if this works or not.